# ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment - Error while installing kafka 3.1.0+java11 in windows

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to setup kafka 3.1.0 with java 11 on my local machine. However, while listing existing topics, I am getting timeout exception.

**Steps followed:**

1. Started zookeeper server:
   zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
2. Started kafka server:
   kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties
3. Command to list topics:
   kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --list

C:\kafka_2.13-3.1.0>kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --list
Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics
[2022-02-19 20:11:37,239] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics
(kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

[Attached stacktrace from command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf47s.jpg)

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. Port 2181 is Zookeeper, not Kafka. Latest kafka tools have removed Zookeeper connection properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this issue. Basically, I enabled listener in server.properties as below,

listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

Then while running list command changed port number to 9092

C:\kafka_2.13-3.1.0>kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:**9092** --list

first_topic

C:\kafka_2.13-3.1.0>

Comment: Hi sir, It for me too but can you explain why we need to change in this manner  ?